# I'm not able to store the data to mysql database using HTML and JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I'm writing a program in Node.js to get the data and store it in database. I'm passing the data from HTML page to JavaScript for validation and to store the data in MySQL database, if the validations are true, but after validation, it's not storing the data in MySQL.

Can you help me identifying the problem?

Code:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

function validateform(){

    var fname = document.myform.fname.value;
    var lname = document.myform.lname.value;
    var email_id = document.myform.email.value;

    if (fname==null || fname==""){
        alert("First Name can't be blank");
            return false;
    }
    else if(lname==null || lname==""){
        alert("Last Name  can't be blank");
            return false;
    }
    else if(email_id.length<6){
        alert("Email must be at least 6 characters long.");
            return false;
    }
    else{

        var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'xxx',
        database: 'example'
        });

        connection.connect(function(err) {
        if(err){
            console.log('Error');
        }
        else{
            console.log('Connected');
            }
        });

        var exampleData = {
            firstName: fname,
            lastName: lname,
            email: email_id
        };


        var query = connection.query('insert into example set ?', exampleData, function (err, result) {
            console.log(query.sql);
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                return;
            }
            console.log(result);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Are any error messages output?

Comment: No errors, it just pass it to success page without storing the data in MySQL.

Comment: How do you call this `validateform` function?

Comment: I'm calling it from my HTML page: 


<form name="myform" method="post" action="success.html" onsubmit="return validateform()" > First name:<br/> <input type="text" name="fname"/> Last name:<br/> <input type="text" name="lname"/> Email ID:<br/> <input type="text" name="email"/> <input type="submit" value="Submit"/> </form>

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your query. Use `values` instead of `set`

Comment: Still the same, it passes to the success page without storing the data in MySQL.

Comment: Can you plz provide your table structure for `example` table

Comment: Do you have the table `example` ?

Comment: Table:
CREATE TABLE example(
 id INT PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
 firstName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 lastName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
 email VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
);